# How to do an in app purchase in AIR for Android?

Tags: android, air, in-app-purchase

Is there a way to make in app purchases in an Android app? Specifically, my app has a flag, a application variable value, that differentiates it from free and paid. So I want to make my free the same as my paid app when they do an in app purchase. I also have a paid version on the market.

If the flag is set then paid functionality works in the free app. How would I enable this in an AIR app for Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **AIR Native Extension** in order to be capable to use Android IAB in your AIR application. [Here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.edu.html) you can find a list of both commercial/free ANE providing several extensions, and some interesting link to tutorials and docs about that topic (eg: [Using the In-App Billing Adobe AIR native extension for Android](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/android-billing-ane.edu.html))

Another valuable resource is [ExtensionsOfAir.com](http://extensionsforair.com/) which provides a set of ANE developed and maintained by the community.